# Bad constructor arguments happened when click a section's visualeditor edit button in MediaWiki

Tags: javascript, php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

MediaWiki's visualeditor does not load when editing a specific chapter, the error is displayed as **Uncaught Error: Bad constructor** arguments in the console

```
Uncaught Error: Bad constructor arguments
    at new Uri (<anonymous>:648:770)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:625:103)
    at Function.each (load.php?lang=zh&modules=jquery%2Coojs-ui-core%2Coojs-ui-widgets%7Cjquery.ui%7Cmmv.bootstrap&skin=gongbi&version=127x7:5:285)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (load.php?lang=zh&modules=jquery%2Coojs-ui-core%2Coojs-ui-widgets%7Cjquery.ui%7Cmmv.bootstrap&skin=gongbi&version=127x7:3:93)
    at scrollToSection (<anonymous>:625:75)
    at activateTarget (<anonymous>:627:479)
    at Object.onEditSectionLinkClick (<anonymous>:639:893)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (load.php?lang=zh&modules=jquery%2Coojs-ui-core%2Coojs-ui-widgets%7Cjquery.ui%7Cmmv.bootstrap&skin=gongbi&version=127x7:70:260)
    at elemData.handle (load.php?lang=zh&modules=jquery%2Coojs-ui-core%2Coojs-ui-widgets%7Cjquery.ui%7Cmmv.bootstrap&skin=gongbi&version=127x7:66:877)
```

The visualeditor should work normally when editing sections，but actually it didn't